# Debug on device iphone error pipe broken?

Tags: iphone

I have a sample app i have installed all the provisioning profile needed and now i am debugging it on device.But when i want to install another app with the same provisioning profile it overwrites the one before it or it gives me an error like pipe broken!
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Simply try debugging again. That happens quite frequently.

Comment: I want to have on my phone what apps i am testing so i don't want them to overwrite. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do your apps have the same app id?  com.myCompany.myApp?  If so then one will always overwrite the other. That's how the device identifies which app is which.

As for broken pipe, try restarting the device and xCode.

Comment: I have com.notifications.pushchat. How do i manage to not overwrite each other?

Comment: You have to give them different ID's.

Comment: I have to create a different app id in the provisionig profile?

Comment: You may need you create another profile or create a wildcard profile.